# Encode/Decode with UTF8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, utf-8, encode

I am trying to encode the text in a rich text box , so it appears as `UTF-8`.
I am having some troubles however, and most online help posts aren't giving me how to return the converted text to the richtextbox.

```
  private void encodeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string textstring;
        string encodedString;
        textstring = richTextBox1.Text;
        byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(textstring);
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        encodedBytes.ToString(encodedString);
        richTextBox1.Text = encodedString;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `richTextBox1.Text = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);`?

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes) to display byte values.

Answer (score 3):

Change `encodedBytes.ToString(encodedString);` to `encodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);`